# How to link two networks with different IP ranges

Tags: networking, subnet

I've got a network on ip range 192.168.0.X.  It has a router with an internal IP on this range that lets it talk to the outside world.

If I create a new network on ip range 192.168.1.X.  How can I get this network to see the first network on a different IP range and more specifically the router on the original range.

The computers are windows and linux based.

Comment: [Edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1082006/edit) the question to answer: Are the 2 IP networks sharing the same physical network (same switch/hub)?

Comment: @hardillb, yes they are.

Answer (score 2):

Your options depend on just how capable your "router" is.

**Option 1**

If the router is capable of assigning multiple IP addresses to it's internal interface (or has multiple interfaces) then you should be able to assign it both `192.168.0.1` and `192.168.1.1` (assuming default gateway for both networks is `xxx.xxx.xxx.1`)

**Option 2**

Pick one of the Linux machines on the network, assign it's interface addresses out of both ranges e.g. `192.168.0.15` and `192.168.1.1` then add a static route to the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet on the router via `192.168.0.15` and enable IP forwarding on the Linux machine.

Comment: appreciate the response....and what would I do with windows machines

Comment: You don't need to touch the windows machines, it's just easier to use one of the Linux machines to route between the 2 subnets